# Multiple instances of same react component

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a react component, a comments feature, to a non-react site.

The site has a news page with infinite scrolling.  Under each news story I want to include the react comments component. I plan to model it after the FB tutorial here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

My question is, how do I dynamically mount each React component to a DOM story element? Basically, I want to have many instances of the same react comments component, but with each instance tied to a unique story (div).

I think I need to render the react component on the server side, where I can dynamically set the `React.renderComponent`.  Any pointers/examples appreciated.

Comment: @jason_gelinas did you ever get this working? I've seen there are naming conflicts with multiple instances on one page, but your use case is a great one for SEO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the post is added you need to have your data and the target dom node (we'll call these variables `data` and `el`)

```
React.render(<MyComponent data={data} />, el);
```

Or without JSX

```
React.render(React.createElement(MyComponent, {data: data}), el);
```

To clean up:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(el);
```

For server side rendering you can do:

```
React.renderToString(React.createElement(MyComponent, {data: data}))
```

and as long as the result of that ends up as `el` on the client, you can mount it with React.render as mentioned above.

Comment: is it OK to mount React elements like you suggest multiple times in the same DOM? I think that is what the question specifically asks:  "I want to have many instances of the same react comments component, but with each instance tied to a unique story (div)"

Comment: Yeah, you can have hundreds of roots.