# React: Insert One Component After Another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very simply I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="App" class="ui container">
    <div id="Keywords" class="left"></div>
    <div id="Users" class="right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="Nav"></div>
</div>
```

And I am appending my components like this:

```
ReactDom.render(<Feed listenTo="keywords" />, document.querySelector('#Keywords'));
ReactDom.render(<Feed listenTo="users" />, document.querySelector('#Users'));
ReactDom.render(<Nav />, document.querySelector('#Nav'));
```

I want to get rid of the `#Keywords` and `#Users` divs. I just want my components to append to the `#App` div. I tried something like this:

```
ReactDom.render(<Feed listenTo="keywords" />, document.querySelector('#App'));
ReactDom.render(<Feed listenTo="users" />, document.querySelector('#App'));
ReactDom.render(<Nav />, document.querySelector('#Nav'));
```

And I ended up getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target
>   container is not a DOM element.

Anyone have an idea of how I can just append those two components into the `#App` div? Do I have to make `#App` a parent component?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="container main">
      <Feed listenTo="users" />
      <Feed listenTo="keywords" />    
      <Nav />
    </div>;
  }
});

React.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I have included this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93xbwn8e/).

It uses the depricated React.render instead of ReactDOM.render - but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks Michael! That was one route I was planning on going.

Comment: Alternatively it seems the consensus is that calling ReactDom.render multiple times is A-OK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302803/is-it-ok-to-use-react-render-multiple-times-in-the-dom

Comment: Hey @MaxBaldwin if you haven't gotten a chance yet check out the fiddle that I added.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I decided to go the route that you suggested.