# Call React.render() multiple time throw error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

From this question ([Is it OK to use React.render() multiple times in the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302803/is-it-ok-to-use-react-render-multiple-times-in-the-dom)) it seem like we can call React.render() multiple times in a page. However when I tried following code I got " _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element." error on the second component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Button} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/Button'
class App extends Component {

  render () {
    </div>;
    return(
        <div><Button>I am a button.</Button></div>

    )
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app2'));


<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <div id="app2" />
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing `div` above the return statement in you render function,apart from that as stated in the **[docs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react)** of `office-ui-fabric-react` Button is being import from `lib` and not `lib/components`

Import it like

```
import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
    
    return(
        <div>I am a button</div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```