# How to Layout a Page w/ Multiple ReactJs Components on a Traditional Webpage

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with determining the best route to integrate various components of a single `React` app on a page within my traditional website. I've worked with React a bit, but they have always been self-contained pieces of content (meaning it fits nicely in one div in the HTML). But now I have a page where I need to sprinkle React into different sections. And each React piece will share various data.

See the attached image. Dark green sections will be `React`. The rest is a traditional `PHP` page pulling in content from a `CMS`.

I'm trying to figure out the best strategy for the `React` portion.

Should I have multiple renders each going to an appropriate div?

```
ReactDOM.render(<Section2 />, document.getElementById("react-app-div1"));
ReactDOM.render(<Section1 />, document.getElementById("react-app-div2"));
```

Since the React elements will all be sharing similar info, am I looking at `Redux` or `Context API` to manage that information?

Or is there a better way? 
Is this antithetical to React, and I should just get all the markup into the React app itself?

I hope this question makes sense.

[image of sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwWGU.gif)

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303179/784060

Comment: Yes thank you. As far as state, what would be the recommendation? A choice made in <Section1 /> will influence <Section 2 />. Would this be where Redux comes in? Or possibly React's Context API?