# What is the difference between React component and React component instance?

Tags: reactjs

I am reading [this](https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-semantics.html#) and it says:

> When a component is purely a result of props alone, no state, the
>   component can be written as a pure function avoiding the need to
>   create a **React component instance**.

What's the difference between a component and a component instance ?

Are they the same ?

EDIT:

- What is the difference between `Component` and `Component Instance` ?
- How do they relate to each-other ?
- Conceptually ?
- How are they represented in computer memory? How does the representation differ ?
- What is a component and what is an instance of that component ? (In memory.) What kind of JS Object ?
- Instance in what sense ? Object oriented sense ?
- Is it true that every component can have (one or more) instance(s) ?
- How many instances can a component have ?
- Does it even make sense to say that an instance can be created for a/every react component ?
- How are react component instances created and how are components created ?

Reason for asking:

I am trying to create a concept map of react to clarify the terminology and how they relate to each other.

Here is a draft:

[image]

Comment: This seems related but does not answer the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112274/multiple-instances-of-same-react-component

Comment: The plain and simple is: a stateless component is one that does not get the lifecycle events like `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`; it literally just renders whatever props you pass it. If you create a `class` that extends `React.Component`, you've now created a stateful component that has access to lifecycle events.

Comment: After a while the answer is - for me : it is the same as in OO, Component is class/type, Component Instance is an object having the type "Component" just like in Java etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic difference is, when it a `Component`, React will run/add all its [Lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle). This will be useful when you have `state` in your component. When you use this component, React will create a `React Component Instance` which will have all the lifecycle methods and other hooks added to it.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  ...
}
```

In some cases, you won't use `state`. In those cases, adding all those lifecycle methods are unnecessary. So, React gives you an way to create an component which will have `render` alone. It is called `PureComponent`. When you use this, there is no need to create a new `Component Instance` because there is no lifecycle methods here. It'll just be a function which can take `props` and return React Elements.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent{
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

**[Update]**

**What is a `Component` and a `Component Instance`?**

Technically, a `Component` in React is a `class` or a `function`.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component{
...
}

//stateless component
const App = (props) => {
...
}
```

When you use that `component`, it'll be instantiated, more like `new App()`. But, React does it by itself in a different way.

For Example:

```
render(){
   return <App/> //Instance of the component App
}
```

Instances are required because, each instance can perform individually. Instances are a copy of original class.

**Simple answer is, `components` will be a `Class` and `component Instance` will be the copy/instance of the class and will be used in `render`**

Hope this explains!

Comment: I see, but what is the difference between `Component` and `Component Instance` ? How do they relate to each-other ? Conceptually ? What is a `component` and what is an instance of that `component` ? Is it true that every `component` can have an instance ? How many instances can a `component` have ? Does it even make sense to say that an instance can be created for a/every react `component` ? How are react `component` instances created ? How is an instance represented vs how is a `component` represented ?

Comment: @jhegedus Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is described here :) https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html - as well

Comment: Haha! Glad you found that. I tried to put that simple.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

A "React component instance" is just an instance that was created from a previously defined class component. See the example below (es6/JSX) which contains both props and state:

```
class MyComponentClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
            example: 'example'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <div>{this.state.example}</div>
            <div>{this.props.example}</div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

If you have no need for state in your component you can use a pure, stateless, functional React component like so:

```
function MyStatelessFunctionalComponent(props) {
    return <div>{this.props.example}</div>;
}
```

Here is some more information about [stateless React components](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.yv0zxjxr5) when they were introduced in React `v0.14`. Since then you have [the ability to use hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) starting in React `v16.8`, which allow you to define a functional component that has state or makes use of the component lifecyle.

As mentioned in some other comments, there are many performance benefits when [using stateless components](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.ttiirkcf4). These types of components are perfect for when you want something purely presentational as an example.

> Since there’s no state or lifecycle methods to worry about, the React team plans to avoid unnecessary checks and memory allocations in future releases.